# Ruby not outputting notation correctly

Tags: ruby

I have a probability function

```
def fac(x)
  (1..x).inject(1, :*)
end


def prob(k, n)
  fac(n) / (fac(k)* fac(n - k)) * (1.0/6.0)**k * 5.0/6.0**(n-k)
end
```

when I do `prob(16.0, 17.0)`

I get the output `5.021664214224737e-10`

Is there a way to get the output to look like `.0000000005021664214224737` instead?

Also the question title might not be correct, please edit if you deem necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind specifying the accuracy manually,

```
"%.25f" % 5.021664214224737e-10
# => "0.0000000005021664214224737"
```

And you can remove the leading `0` by applying `[1..-1]` to it.

Answer (score 1):

[Convert the float to a BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/Float.html#method-i-to_d) then [use `to_s` to achieve floating-point notation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

prob(16.0, 17.0).to_d.to_s("F")
=> "0.000000000502166421422474"
```